# Regular Expression. 20 Alphabetical letters and up to 2 of ( . - _ )

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to build up a regex pattern for the html input field which only allows up to 20 combined alphabetical letters and digits which can only have up to two of Dashes(-), Underscores(_) and fullstops (.)

So something like only two of the symbols allowed and any amount of letters and digits allowed, combined they've got to be between 4 and 20.

What would the pattern for this be?

An sample (non functioning) version could be like `[A-Za-z0-9([\._-]{0,2})]{4,20}`

**Solution:**

I decided to go with @pascalhein @Honore Doktorr answer which is to use a lookahead.
The final pattern is `^(?=[A-Za-z0-9]*([._-][A-Za-z0-9]*){0,2}$)[A-Za-z0-9._-]{4,20}$`

Comment: Could you provide any of your attempts? Please also provide examples of valid and invalid input text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx for password strength](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-for-password-strength)

Comment: Something like `[A-Za-z0-9([\._-]{0,2})]{4,20}`

Comment: If you provide sample input strings help will come quicker. Also, what do you mean by up to 2? Zero, one or 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can verify the length with a lookahead at the beginning:

```
^(?=.{4,20}$)
```

Then list all the cases that are allowed for your regex separately:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]* (no special chars)

[A-Za-z0-9]*[._-][A-Za-z0-9]* (one special char)

[A-Za-z0-9]*[._-][A-Za-z0-9]*[._-][A-Za-z0-9]* (two special chars)
```

It isn't beautiful, but I believe it should work. This is the final expression:

```
^(?=.{4,20}$)([A-Za-z0-9]*|[A-Za-z0-9]*[._-][A-Za-z0-9]*|[A-Za-z0-9]*[._-][A-Za-z0-9]*[._-][A-Za-z0-9]*)$
```

Edit:

Actually, it might be nicer to test the number of special characters with a lookahead instead:

```
^(?=[A-Za-z0-9]*([._-][A-Za-z0-9]*){0,2}$)[A-Za-z0-9._-]{4,20}$
```

Comment: Very elegant! I tried to answer this question, but I was stuck on how to limit the length of the total string while allowing a flexible number of alphanumeric characters. Nicely explained, too.

Comment: @pascalhein: alternatively, assert that there are no more than two special characters w/ a negative lookahead, `(?!(?:.*[-_.]){3,}`. Full expression `^(?=.{4,20}$)(?!(?:.*[-_.]){3,})[-_.a-zA-Z0-9]*$`, [sample](http://refiddle.com/refiddles/555b618e75622d5b8e080400).

Comment: @celerno I tested at regexr.com, but is there a problem with what you are showing? As I understand, it should not be matched because it contains 4 special characters and only 2 are allowed

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to not to use a Regex when there are functions for the porpuse you want to achieve.

An advice I give to jrs on this topic is to use a regex for single porpuses, if there is more than one porpuse, use more regex.

to answer your question:

- 1 your valid characters from start to end.

  var 1stregex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._-]{4,20}$/;
- 2 Count must be 0 to 2, which in javascript is .match().length.

  var 2ndregex = /([._-])/;

  if(myText.match(1stregex) && myText.match(2ndregex).length <=2)
   { isvalid=true; }

Comment: I can see where you're coming from but as I'm trying to use this with HTML's pattern tag to have more support and avoid having to write actual code for validation I decided to use a regex instead.

Comment: sometimes is better (in terms of clean code and time spent) to write a few lines. my opinion.