# Equivalent regex for this webApi PasswordValidator

Tags: regex, angularjs, validation, asp.net-web-api, passwords

I'd like to validate the password before the form is submit using Regex, Id like to know what whats the equivalent regex for the following PasswordValidator settings:

```
        UserManager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };
```

im using the AngujarJS pattern validation.
Example:

```
 <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword" ng-minlength="6" np-pattern="/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$/" ng-model="userData.Password" />
<p class="alert-danger" ng-show="userDetails.inputPassword.$error.pattern">The Password is invalid</p>
```

But it simply ignore it.

Thank you very much!

**Update 1**
with the help of accepted answer i come to the following regex ^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$ and added the length validation as ng-minlength="6" for some reason the pattern validation doesnt work on IE9 where the validation prevent the user save, rendering it totally useless.

**Update 2**

By suggested by stribizhev, changing the any symbol regex to (?=.*[\W_]) fixed IE9 validation, so it works 100% in IE9, final code is

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword" ng-minlength="6" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_]).+$/" ng-model="userData.Password" />
<p class="alert-danger" ng-show="userDetails.inputPassword.$error.pattern || userDetails.inputPassword.$error.minlength">The Password is invalid</p>
```

thank you all very much

Comment: Can you show your attempts?

Comment: I would check this `^(?=.*[^a-zA-Z\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6}$` not sure if it is correct.

Comment: The non letter/digit needs to be better defined. Also, in total, the available/allowed characters should be better defined, like at least non-whitespace, 6 or more:  `\S{6,}`

Comment: @montelof - Fyi: On your **update 2** - Just to be clear, `(?=.*[\W_])` is _exactly identical_ to `(?=.*(_|[^\w]))` in function. Any speed difference due to the alternation is _not_ noticeable in your context. And in no way affects backtracking whatsoever. As for `fixed IE9 validation`, that's not even relavent, or remotely possible !!

Comment: @sln I know its weird, using chrome it works either way, but in IE9 only the second one did it. I dont know if its something related to the pipe maybe.

Comment: @montelof - `I dont know if its something related to the pipe maybe`. I'm pretty sure `pipes`/alternation was included when the first regular expression engine was designed. That would be a long time ago. Its probably something else at fault. I would be worried about the integrity of an engine that appears to have a problems with an alternation. I would separately test a piped expression both inside and outside a lookahead assertion. If it doesn't work inside a lookahead assertion, the engine integrity is in the _crapper_ !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}$
```

I found that answer on SO which will give you hint how to construct your own regex https://stackoverflow.com/a/5142164/2892208

Comment: thank you the last comma is what i was missing it looks like this ^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*(_|[^\w])).{6,}+$

Comment: I advise turning `(?=.*(_|[^\w]))` to `(?=.*[\W_])`. Less backtracking, quicker regex. Do you allow spaces in the password?

Comment: the expression I used works only on chrome but not for length validation, for that i had to use the ng-minlength validation.

Comment: thank you stribizhev, your solution fixed the validation in IE9.