# Need to Add regex (php) for at least 1 special char

Tags: php, regex

```
$uppercase = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $motpass);
$lowercase = preg_match('@[a-z]@', $motpass);
$number    = preg_match('@[0-9]@', $motpass);
$special   = preg_match('@[@#$%^&+=]@', $motpass);  <---( PROBLEM HERE )

if (!$uppercase || !$lowercase || !$number || !$special || strlen($motpass) < 8)


{

    $motpass_error='NO GOOD';
    $error=true;
}
    else
{
    $motpass = $_POST['motpass'];
}
```

Im looking for regex (All specials Chararcter or Most )

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Too many unnecessary checks. You can validate your password strength in one go, using a single (but complex) `preg_match()` pattern. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-for-password-strength), for instance, or try googling "strong password regex" for more examples.

Comment: I would go also with lookahead assertions.

Comment: Yes, but eventually I would like to add custom error msg for each condition.

Comment: ex: uppercase ----> echo; your pass needs at least one upercase , Will this be possible with one single pattern. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$special   = preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z\d]/', $motopass);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try code like below.

```
$uppercase = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $motpass);
$lowercase = preg_match('@[a-z]@', $motpass);
$number    = preg_match('@[0-9]@', $motpass);
$special   = preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z\d]/', $string);
```

OR

```
$uppercase = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $motpass);
$lowercase = preg_match('@[a-z]@', $motpass);
$number    = preg_match('@[0-9]@', $motpass);
$special   = preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$%^&]).*$/');

if (!$uppercase || !$lowercase || !$number || !$special || strlen($motpass) < 8)


{

    $motpass_error='NO GOOD';
    $error=true;
}
    else
{
    $motpass = $_POST['motpass'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

'\w' matches word(alphabet or numeric) character where as '\W' matches non-word (special characters) character.

So using non-word character makes simple.
Try below regex:

```
$special   = preg_match('/\W+/', $string);
```

'+' in expression represent one or more word characters.