# Android: Checking for special characters

Tags: android, authentication, passwords, special-characters

I'm currently creating an app with a login screen. I've got everything setup but i want to make the password follow a normal set of rules: The password must have a special character (!, @, #, $, %...), A number, and a uppercase letter. I'm pretty sure i know how to do 2 of the 3. The problem im having is making an if statement to check to see if the password has a special character. I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this. Any solution to do this?

Comment: you want to do this android side?

Comment: You can create a regex, something similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-to-validate-password-strength

Comment: i used .net to server side and Microsoft  have class for validate any thing like password

Comment: @mehrdad Yes id like to do this all through within the main activity itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the given method for checking **special Character**. you can replace it's `regex` according to your need.

```
public Boolean isSpecialCharAvailable(String s) {
        //int counter =0;
        if (s == null || s.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9]");//replace this with your needs
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        // boolean b = m.matches();

        boolean b = m.find();
        if (b == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```