# Regex for combination of given rules

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, jquery-validate

I'm trying to write regex to validate the password for the given rule.

Passwords must be at least 8 characters in length and **contain at least 3 of the following 4 types of characters:**

- lower case letters (i.e. a-z)
- upper case letters (i.e. A-Z)
- numbers (i.e. 0-9)
- special characters (e.g. !@#$&*)

I was going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-to-validate-password-strength) discussion and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-to-validate-password-strength#answer-5142164) really great answer over there.

Now I'm trying to write regex for the mentioned requirements and I came up with the solution like this

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}|
(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}|
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}|
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}|
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}$
```

and it is working perfect see [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/Drwq39CvTi) but I want to optimize these regex and I'm not sure If there are any way to simplify this.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: Optimizing this regex means splitting it into several smaller regexps. They will be really more readable and maintainable.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I will really appreciate If you can provide any useful link here, Thank you

Comment: If the regex works fine, perhaps, a better place to ask this question would be [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3):

Do yourself (and anyone who will work on that app in the future) a favour, and split the regexp in 4:

```
{
  :lowercase => /regex_for_lowercase/,
  :uppercase => /regex_for_uppercase/,
  :digits => /regex_for_digits/,
  :symbols => /regex_for_symbols/,
}
```

then count how many of these 4 rules the password matches. It will also give you the chance to show more helpful error message if the entered password does not validate.