# Jquery validation not working for strong password in mvc5

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I am developing one application in mvc5 with jquery. I am trying to implement regular expression for password as below.
This is the piece of code from jquery.validationEngine-en.js

```
"requiredOutLogin": {
                    "regex":/^(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{8}$/,
                    "alertText": "*Password should contain atleast one special character,one number and one upper case letter",
                    "alertTextCheckboxMultiple": "* Please select an option",
                    "alertTextCheckboxe": "* This checkbox is required",
                    "alertTextDateRange": "* Both date range fields are required"
                },
```

This is my razor view code.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.usr_username, new { id = "txtusername", @maxlength = "15",@minlength="8",@class = "form-control validate[requiredOutLogin] text-input", @placeholder = "Username" })
```

I am not able to validate the password here. If i left blank the password field then it will popup required message(*Password should contain atleast one special character,one number and one upper case letter) but if i enter just test then it will login(if the password is correct). Above piece of regular expression not validation but it will display alertText if i keep the field blank. I copied regular expression from [Regex to validate password strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-to-validate-password-strength). May I know why i am not able to validate here? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason your not using a `[RegularExpression]` on your property and jquery validation?

Comment: Thank you. I am not doing any server side validation.

Comment: Why not? You must always validate on the server (any one can bypass your script)

Comment: I agree. I can validate it in server side for security purpose. But Here also i  am trying to validate.

Comment: It started working fine after change to as below. @class = "form-control validate[custom[requiredOutLogin]] text-input". Thanks for trying to help me Mr Stephen Muecke. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove Id property from textbox.

Strongly typed html helpers are automatic assign Id="" name="" attribute with model property name to every textbox.