# Find longest sub-string without any number and at least one upper case character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I came across a programming exercise and was stuck. The problem is:

> You need to define a valid password for an email but the only
>   restrictions are:
>
> The password must contain one uppercase character and the password should not have numeric digit.
>
> Now, given a String, find the length of the longest substring which is
>   a valid password.

I am able to solve this in Java but not able to figure out how to do in javascript.

Here is my Java solution:

```
public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
    int n = s.length();
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    int ans = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < n && j < n) {
        if (!set.contains(s.charAt(j))){
            set.add(s.charAt(j++));
            ans = Math.max(ans, j - i);
        }
        else {
            set.remove(s.charAt(i++));
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Am sure this is present somewhere on SO. Search for it before you start getting downvotes and close votes.

Comment: I already did but I am not able to find it in javascript.

Comment: Based on given specifications I came up with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/gbswYI/1/). Also provide some valid and invalid matches according to your specifications.

Comment: It's there in the question already.

Comment: There could be many combinations like `aBa0a`. In this case should `aBa` considered as a match ?

Comment: Yeah I think so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142239/discussion-between-rahul-and-user5447339).

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-to-validate-password-strength .you can change this regex pattern as your wish . more explanation also there.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would want to get the substring? Your case is easily solvable using regex.

Answer (score 2):

Use two Regular Expressions to validate desired strings: `\D+` and `[A-Z]`:

```js
try {
   var o = "a0Ba".match(/\D+/g).map(x => x.match(/[A-Z]/) ? x.length : -1);
   console.log(Math.max.apply(null, o));
} catch (e) {
   console.log(-1);
}
```

Comment: Impressive code. Would it be an alternative to map `x => x.match(/[A-Z]/) ? x.length : -1` in line three and then do `Math.max.apply(null, arrayOfX)` saving yourself `filter`, `sort`, and `typeof`? (bow)

Comment: Thank you, applied.

Answer (score 1):

> The password must contain one uppercase character and the password should not have numeric digit.

Based on your current specification following regex will match all valid sub-string from given string. From there on you can check for string lengths for longest sub-string.

**Regex:** `(?=[^\d]*[A-Z])[^\d]+`

**Explanation:**

`(?=[^\d]*[A-Z])` will lookforward for `non-digits` followed by an Upper Case letter.

`[^\d]+` will match more than one characters other than digits.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gbswYI/3/)**</kbd>

Check out the following demo.

```js
document.getElementById('btnfindLength').onclick = function() {
  // Try with input "aa0Baa0aaBaa00aa0Ba"
  var re = /(?=[^\d]*[A-Z])[^\d]+/g;
  var str = document.getElementById('st').value;
  var match;
  var len = 0;
  var longestSubString = null;
  do {
    match = re.exec(str);

    if (match != null) {
      console.log(match + " " + match[0].length);
      if (match[0].length > len) {
        longestSubString = match;
        len = match[0].length;
      }
    }
  } while (match);
  if (len != 0) {
    alert("Longest substring is `" + longestSubString + "` having length " + len);
  } else {
    alert('No substring found.');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="st">
<input type="button" id="btnfindLength" value="Find Length">
```

Comment: _"If there is no such string, then return -1"_

Comment: No, it will match **all** valid substrings. Regexp does not have the brains to find the longest one.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov: How so ? It is [matching](https://regex101.com/r/gbswYI/4/) all valid substrings.

Answer (score 0):

I've literally translated your Java code into Javascript code, but I'm not sure that your code works, anyway if you want to do it with Javascript, see follow:

```js
function lengthOfLongestSubstring(s) {
    var n = s.length;
    var set = [];
    var ans = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < n && j < n) {
        if (!set.indexOf(s.charAt(j))){
            set.push(s.charAt(j++));
            ans = Math.max(ans, j - i);
        }
        else {
            set = set.splice(s.charAt(i++), 1);
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

function test() {
  var input = document.getElementById("txtTest");
  var val = input.value;
  console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring(val));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtTest">
<input type="button" id="btnTest" onclick="test()" value="Test">
```

Comment: This seems to fail for `a0aaBa` in which longest substring will be `aaBa`

Comment: Your code fails because your `set` isn't a hashset. There are no hashsets for Javascript, and you need to make it yourself (if you want to use a hashset).

Comment: In that example Java HashSet is used like an ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.match()` with `RegExp` `/[\DA-Z]+/g` to match one or more characters which are not digit characters, including uppercase letters. If no matches are found in string  set variable to `-1`, else use `.map()`, `RegExp.prptotype.test()` to check if match contain `[A-Z]`, if `true`, get `.length` of each matching substring, else return `-1`. Pass resulting array to `Math.max()` called with `Function.prototype.apply()` to get greatest number from resulting array of numbers.

```js
let checkstr = str => {
  let matches = str.match(/[\DA-Z]+/g);
  return matches 
         ? Math.max.apply(Math
           , matches.map(match => /[A-Z]/.test(match) ? match.length : -1)) 
         : -1
};

console.log(checkstr("a0Ba"), checkstr("a0bb"), checkstr("aa0aaBa"));
```

Comment: For string `aa0aaBa` this will also match `aa` as match. It should have atleast one Upper Case letter.

Comment: For `a0bb` it gives 0 but instead it should give -1?