# How can I concat javascript regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following Regex expressions:

- check length: `[\w\W]{8,}`
- has letters & digits: `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])`
- has letters and special chars: `[\a-zA-z]{1,}[@#$!%^&*]{1,}`
- has digits and special chars: `[\d]{1,}[@#$!%^&*]{1,}`
- has a digit or letter 4 or more times in a row: `([a-z0-9])\1{3,}`

I would like to join them into one single regex:

```
(check length) && (has letters & digits || has letters and special chars || has digits and special chars) && has a digit or letter 4 or more times in a row
```

Is there a way to take these patterns and concatenate them into one single regex expression?

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=javascript+%22regular+expression%22+OR+regex+OR+regexp+password+validation+example - here is the principle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-to-validate-password-strength

Comment: That's a weird rule: "has a digit or letter 4 or more times in a row"

Comment: Thats what the product designers want, no number or charachter repeating for more than 3-4 times...