# Using regex, how to match special chars and numbers anywhere in a password?

Tags: python, regex, special-characters

The only special char position that will match is the end of a password. If the special char is at the beginning, or anywhere other than the end,  it will fail to match and reject the password.

```python
import re

while True:
    password = input("Please enter a password containing at least 6 letters, \n "
                "one number, one capital letter, and at least one special character. ")

    pattern = r"[A-Z]+?[A-Za-z]{6,}?[0-9]+?[^a-zA-Z0-9]+?"

    if not re.search(pattern, password):
        print("Please try again")

    else:
        print("Your new password is: ", password)
        break
```

I would like to accept passwords that contain special chars and numbers anywhere in them, not just at the end, e.g.

- `@#$Chuckles23`
- `Chuck#$les23`
- `23Chuckles@#$`

I've tried using regex code suggested in other answers, but so far none of them work for my scenario.

Comment: See the solution above or this for a regex solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-to-validate-password-strength

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using lookaheads in your password regex pattern:

```
pattern = r'^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{6,}$'
if not re.search(pattern, password):
    print("Please try again")
```

Here is a brief explanation of the regex pattern:

```
^                        from the start of the password
    (?=.*[0-9])          assert that at least one digit is present
    (?=.*[A-Z])          assert that at least one capital letter is present
    (?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])   assert one special character
    .{6,}                then match any 6 or more characters
$                        end of the password
```

Comment: Sorry, started typing mine in mobile before I realized you posted. Only difference is how we interpret the six characters thing.

Comment: FWIW, I think your interpretation is more intuitively correct, but mine is what OP had coded originally.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I also posted this from a mobile phone :-)

Comment: This is great but it might cause backtracks. IMHO, something like `(?=\D*\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\w*\W).{6,}` will give better performance.

Comment: @cem I disagree, and the lookaheads I use should not backtrack.  And I prefer my version to what you used.

Comment: It's that time of day :). Speaking of backtracking, I've added the equivalent lookbehind approach to pretend like our answers are different.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It has to backtrack internally or it will not be capturing anything because of the star. There's actually no difference between `.*[0-9]` and `(?=.*[0-9])`, both of these has to eat all the characters and then start to backtrack, except when engine leaves the lookahead, it'll forget about it. [example](https://regex101.com/r/w7EMyq/1)

Comment: @cem I get it :-)  We could also just make the dots lazy, I think, e.g. use `(?=.*?[0-9])`.  But, I typically don't see your suggestion being used in practice.  The thing is, the lookaheads at most require just one scan of the input, which is linear and not really a big penalty.

Comment: Thank you Tim!  You couldn't have made it more clear and easy to understand, and your solution has worked!  Thank you, as well, to M.P!

Answer (score 1):

This could be done via lookaheads. Each criterion could be checked by lookahead this way:

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=(?:.*[A-Za-z]){6,})(?=(?:.*[0-9]))(?=(?:.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])).*
```

You can use `re.match` and `re.fullmatch` in addition to `re.search` for the validator.

An equivalent expression can be obtained using lookbehinds:

```
.*(?<=.*[A-Z])(?<=(?:.*[A-Za-z]){6,})(?<=(?:.*[0-9]))(?<=(?:.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]))
```

You can even mix and match e.g.:

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=(?:.*[A-Za-z]){6,}).*(?<=(?:.*[0-9]))(?<=(?:.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]))
```

Functionally, the approaches are all equivalent. The differences are mostly aesthetic, although of course there may be implementation details that cause small timing differences as well.

Comment: Variable width lookbehinds are only supported by very few languages (e.g. C#).  In general, they are considered bad and run the risk of backtracking problems.

Comment: @Tim. I only understand regex at a very high level (jack of all trades, ...). Do you happen to know of a good place to read more?

Comment: If i had to recommend a single site, it would be [rexegg](http://www.rexegg.com/).  But, regex is just something you pick up as you go along.  There is no one stop shop for it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've learned a lot even from just a cursory skim. Just part of going along.