# Javascript regular expression that matches at least 2 character (with special characters included) 2 numbers and max length of 8

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to put the following rule in a regular expression to use in my javascript code but with no luck,

This is the rule: at least 2 characters including special characters, 2 digits and a minimum of length is 8

my regular expression

```
/^(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){2})(?=(?:\D*\d){2})[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}$/
```

Comment: Are you trying to use [regex to validate a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-to-validate-password-strength)?

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a

Comment: is this correct  /(...?.?.?.?.?.?)/

Comment: Why are you only using 1 regex? Use a different for each different rule

Comment: @nickzoum what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var regexTests = {
  "Needs at least 2 letters or special characters": /(.*[A-Z!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{}|;:<>?,./]){2,}/i,
  "Needs at least 2 digits": /(.*\d){2,}/,
  "Needs at least 8 total characters": /.{8,}/
};

function testText(txt) {
  return Object.keys(regexTests).filter(function(error) {
    return !regexTests[error].test(txt);
  });
}

console.log(testText("12"));
console.log(testText("gg"));
console.log(testText("g1"));
console.log(testText("g11f"));
console.log(testText("23df78sd"));
```